# Is Orthogonal in LWJGL 2D or 3D?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl3

I'm attempting to develop an orthogonal game with lwjgl 3 and OpenGL in Eclipse, but I can't find an answer for rendering objects in 2D or 3D. Are both applicable? And if so what are the advantages of either one?
I would also like to rotate my camera if that changes your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The orthographic camera should almost always only be used in 2d. Instead you should use the perspectivecamera

You can read more about the orthographic camera here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

Read more about creating 3d games in libgdx here:
https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/

On this site it is explained why you should use the perspective camera for 3d instead of the orthographic camera:                                                http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/08/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-16-Cameras.aspx

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use it for both.

It makes `z` coordinate not affect any vertex positions, so you can use it for 2D games.

But it also allows you to use features like z-buffering and there is nothing wrong with rendering 3D objects with it.